# How do I reopen a question wrongly closed by someone

Tags: support, status-completed, reopen-request

I asked this question:
[Work for a company in a different country while on tourist visa in Austrlia?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/161485/work-for-a-company-in-a-different-country-while-on-tourist-visa-in-austrlia)

My question is related to Australia but someone (without reading the question) marked it as duplicate for answers related to the US.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ask the community or a moderator to re-open.
Your request here was seen and acted upon.